# How I can extract, in Linux, a string contained in the files by associating it with the name of the file that contains it

Tags: linux, bash, text, directory, grep

I have a set of files in a directory:

```
file1.jdl
file2.jdl
...
filen.jdl
```

each file can contains such a string,
for example the **file1.jdl** contains

```
runexe EXE1 $str1 str2 ...
...other stuff
runexe FILE_EXE2 abc ... ...
...other stuff
```

How can I extract, using a script, a list containing a pair of data like this, without file path and without the other strings that could be present after the first string next to runexe ?

```
file1.jdl EXE1 
file1.jdl FILE_EXE2
...
filen.jdl ...
```

Comment: Have you tried `awk '$1=="runexe"{print FILENAME,$2}' *.jdl`?

Comment: @oguzismail thanks for the advice, it remains to remove the path

Comment: @famedoro, I have added a cd to the script so you don't need to strip the pathname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the files.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /path/to/file/ || exit

for file in *.jdl; do
  awk '/EXE/{print FILENAME, $0}' "$file"
done
```

That would be fine if you don't need to do a recursive search, otherwise you need to use `find` or the shell option `globstar`

Comment: Sorry, but I have left out a detail:
the program works, but it gives me an output like:
/path/file1.jdl runexe WRITEMIN $ str1 $ str2 $ str3
how can i remove the path and strings $ str1 $ str2 $ str3 and get only the file1.jdl WRITEMIN pair

Comment: Could you please update your post and add the details.

Comment: You use what @oguz ismail posted for the `awk` and use the `${file##*/}` to remove the pathname from the filename.

Comment: I have this error fatal cannot open file for reading no such file or  directory

Comment: Use the correct path for the files, e.g. replace `/path/to/file` with the correct path where your files are.

Comment: the path is correct, the problem is when I use "$ {file##*/}" instead of "$file"

Comment: Right, ill revert the to the previous.